# Streaming send file from GCS to Windows Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, windows-server

I want to create a job running on DataFlow (streaming format).
The function will be to receive files from Google Cloud Storage (Path: gs: // mybucket ....) and transfer this file to a server, running Windows Server.

Can anybody suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Windows is not supported as a storage destination. Dataflow has a set of connectors that are used for data transfers/storage. Windows server is not one of them.

This link provides the current connectors that are avaiable.

[Apache Beam Built-in I/O Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/)

Comment: Thanks John Hanley,

I have created a Job running daily and located in Windows Server, this Job can download the file from this GCS.

My intention is to create a Job with the same function, but created from DataFlow.

Thanks for your help.